# angularjs dynamic form with different field types

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-directive

In my current project I need to create a dynamic form using AngularJS.
I am already building the form following the ideas from this video [here.](https://youtu.be/G5MzkDJQkoQ?t=1174)

I can't seem to get the submitted data back to my controller. I only receive undefined in the console log.

Currently the data for the form is resolved in ui-router before the state is loaded, then copied to the controller's data property.

Unlike the video our form requires that questions are broken down into sections.

There is a ng-repeat over each section in the data, then a nested ng-repeat goes over each question. The type is determined and the proper directive for the question/field type is loaded to via ng-switch.

I whipped up a small Plunker to help illustrate as well.
https://plnkr.co/edit/6dCnHiFDEYu03kfX07mr

Finally there are some types I am unsure how to handle, such as address or phone number which will be considered one question type but have multiple fields.

(e.g. [Street] [City] [State] [Zip])

Controller

```
namespace portal.dashboard.form{
class formCtrl{
    formData: portal.domain.interfaces.IHousingRequest;

    static $inject = ["formResolve"];
    constructor(private formResolve:any) {

        this.formData= this.loadHousingRequestFormData;
    }

    public submit(isValid,data) {
        if (isValid) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
}
angular
    .module("portal")
    .controller("formCtrl", formCtrl);
}
```

Directive for input type text

```
namespace portal.directives {
function inputText(): ng.IDirective {
    return {
        scope: {
            model: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope: ng.IScope) {
            var directiveScope = $scope.$parent.$parent;
        },
        controllerAs:'vm',
        templateUrl: 'form/templates/input-text.html'            
    }
}

angular
    .module("portal")
    .directive("inputText", inputText);
}
```

input type html

```
<input type="text"
       ng-model="model"/>
```

HTML

```
    <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.submit(form.$valid, data)" novalidate>

    <!-- Section repeat -->
    <div ng-repeat="section in vm.formData.sections track by $index">
        <section>
            <div>
                <h4>
                    {{section.name}}<br />
                    <small ng-show="section.description">{{section.description}}</small>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <section>

                <!-- Section questions repeat -->
                <div ng-form="formFields" ng-repeat="field in section.fields track by $index">
                    <label>
                        {{field.name}}<br />
                        <small>{{field.description}}</small>
                    </label>

                    <!-- input field switch -->
                    <div ng-switch="field.type">
                        <div ng-switch-when="Text">
                            <input-text model="data.answer[$index]">
                            </input-text>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="Email">
                            <input-email model="data.answer[$index]">
                            </input-email>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to init `$scope.data = {};` before using it, also use correct `sectionIndex` and `fieldIndex` to populate the answer:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.sections = [{
    name: 'User Info',
    description: 'I\'m a description.',
    fields: [{
      label: "Name",
      type: "text"
    }, {
      label: "Email",
      type: "email"
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Pet Info',
    description: '',
    fields: [{
      label: "Pet Breed",
      type: "text"
    }]
  }];

  $scope.submit = function(isValid, data) {
    console.log('submit fired');
    if (isValid) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
});


app.directive('inputText', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      model: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      var directiveScope = $scope.$parent.$parent;
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="model"/>'
  }

});

app.directive('inputEmail', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      model: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      var directiveScope = $scope.$parent.$parent;
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    template: '<input type="email" ng-model="model"/>'
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="form" ng-submit="submit(form.$valid, data)" novalidate>

    <!-- Section repeat -->
    <div ng-repeat="(sectionIndex, section) in sections track by $index">
        <section>
            <div>
                <h4>
                    {{section.name}}<br />
                    <small ng-show="section.description">{{section.description}}</small>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <section>

                <!-- Section questions repeat -->
                <div ng-form="formFields" ng-repeat="(fieldIndex, field) in section.fields track by $index">
                    <label>
                        {{field.label}}<br />
                    </label>

                    <!-- input field switch -->
                    <div ng-switch="field.type">
                        <div ng-switch-when="text">
                            <input-text model="data.answer[sectionIndex][fieldIndex]">
                            </input-text>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="email">
                            <input-email model="data.answer[sectionIndex][fieldIndex]">
                            </input-email>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
  </body>
```

Also I'm not sure why do you need this [`var directiveScope = $scope.$parent.$parent;`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) in your directive's controller, do you really need this?

Comment: You're right that isn't needed, the video I linked to also linked to a github page. As I was referencing that I just put it in thinking it did something but looking back at it I see I don't need it for the way I'm intending to build the form.

Comment: @gboh glad it helped you :)